# Printing List as a String doesn't print all the values

Tags: python

I am trying to Print the List of Integers as Characters in Python, 
But when I am trying to Print it the first few values are being missing,

Here is what is happening,

```
S = [55, 58, 5, 13, 14, 12, 22, 20, 70, 83, 90, 69, 84, 91, 80, 91]
# Now create an empty String,
D = ""
for i in S:
    D += chr(i)

D = ', '.join(map(str, D))
print(D)
```

The final output is,

```
, ♫, ♀, ▬, ¶, F, S, Z, E, T, [, P, [
```

Clearly, the `chr` values for `55 , 58, 5` and `13` are not printed

Here is the value which are not printed,

```
7:♣
```

The `chr` value of `13` is perhaps a space or enter key. This is just my guess because when I am printing `chr(13)` , nothing shows up.
But why it is removing the first three values too. ?

However, If I apply the condition,

```
if i == 13:
    i = i-1
```

The code prints all the values,

```
7, :, ♣, ♀, ♫, ♀, ▬, ¶, F, S, Z, E, T, [, P, [
```

Comment: Here's a [link](http://www.asciitable.com/) to an ASCII table. From there, you can see that you may have issues printing out some of those other character values as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ascii 13 is carriage return(`\r`, enter key). Think as in type writer, it returns the cursor to start of the line, but it doesn't create a new line(`\n`), so when you print something, it overwrites what was in that line before. Look at this:

```
for i in range(10):
    print("\r%d" % i, end="")
    sleep(1)
```

Extra information: On Unix based systems, `\n` implies carriage return and new line, but on Windows systems, you should specify new line(`\n`) and carriage return(`\r`) explicitly. That's why text files created on Unix based systems looks like one long continious line on Windows.

Comment: What Condition am i suppose to apply to make it reversible ? for example if i set if(i==13): i=12,
Then when I will apply reverse algorithm and write, if i==12: i=13, then other chars with value 12 will also become 13.

Comment: Do not try to print this line use repr instead. `print(repr( ", ".join(map(str, map(chr, S)))))`

Comment: Thanks it works, but how to reverse it then ? I mean how to print their equivalent integer values again ?

Comment: Look at `ord` function.